# How to change ListView border when mouse is over and selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

This is my `ListView` items after i made few changes:

```
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border
                 BorderBrush="White"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

`Background color` is `Transparent` and `Foreground color` is `White`.

While `MouseOver` or `ListView item selected` nothing changed, this mean that the currect view is not changing and i want to change the `BorderColor` in `MouseOver` to `White` and while `Selected` i want to change the `BorderColor`  to blue.

Edit:

After try the code example this 2 lines:

```
<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/
```

received error that the resource Item.SelectedActive.Bachground could not be resolved and resource Item.SelectedActive.Border could not be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Change MouseOver and Selected Colors have tao add Triggers for ListViewItem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                      <Border
             BorderBrush="White"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="White"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Now received the resource FocusVisual cannot be resolved the line Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/> -- what does it mean ?

Comment: could you please change the line as <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>

Comment: Now that's works but 2 things stop working; 1. the foreground text color become blue (was white) 2. inside my listview i only can see now my class name without the properties in each column

Comment: please add <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/> for getting white color as foreground. if it works dont forget to vote

Comment: This works now but the items inside the ListView is without my Class properties, i can see only Namespace.ClassName

Comment: i think you are updating your model wrongly through Itemsource. could you check once the model?

Comment: i have this in my ListView XAML code: ItemsSource="{Binding dataList} - what i need to do in order to solve it ? (remove it not helped)